# How to integrate whatsapp in servicenow?

Tags: twilio, integration, whatsapp, servicenow, infobip

I am trying to integrate whatsapp in servicenow instance. I tried to use twilio and infobip to achieve this but not able to configure properly. Can someone assist?

I tried twilio and infobip to integrate whatsapp. I want to be able to send messages on whatsapp to caller's mobile number whenever an update is made in incident.

Answer (score 0):

If the Servicenow can trigger a webhook when some update happens, you can create a Serverless function in your Twilio account that'll receive the customer's phone and the message that needs to be sent and trigger this message to the customer.

To test, you can use the (Twilio Sandbox number)[https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/sandbox] to do your tests, and if it works, you can buy a Twilio Number, approve Whatsapp to it and use this number as your main number to send updates.

Some links that can be useful:

- https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/api/message-resource#create-a-message-resource
- https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/self-sign-up
- https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/tutorial/send-whatsapp-notification-messages-templates
- https://www.twilio.com/docs/serverless/functions-assets/quickstart/send-sms-and-mms

I hope that it can help you.